# Exact same code, sizes and ratio on webpage. why?

Tags: html, css

I have the exact same code on different pages that I am currently clone coding off a chat app.

They are exact same copies of the code copy and pasted.

Why are they in different sizes when viewed on web browser?

I understand it may change due to the amount of content I put on the page.

If so how do i change it so that it is the same as all other pages.

All other pages are the same. Exception for chat and find pages.

Please visit my github to view the codes as they are quite a bit.

Thanks in advance team !

https://github.com/Helllper/koko_clone_April_2023

The code is as below exactly the same as all other pages.

```html
<div class="status-bar">
  <div class="status-bar__column">
    <span>No Service</span>
    <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- TO Do: Wifi Icon-->
  <div class="status-bar__column">
    <span>15:33</span>
  </div>
  <div class="status-bar__column">
    <span>88%</span>
    <i class="fas fa-battery-full fa-lg"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-bolt fa-sm"></i>
    <!-- Battery Icon  -->
    <!-- Lightning Icon  -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David I have re-edited the post apologies.

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  In the code shown, what specifically isn't producing the result you expect?  What result were you expecting and why?

Comment: @David sorry I went full retard. I had differnt zoom settings on my computer and raged over how it does not look the same despite the code.... God damn.... T_T